# How do I select a id inside bootstrap's label tag

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have html like this:

```
`<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" disabled="true" id="ojtm.inform_infoy" name="ojtm.inform_info" path="ojtm.inform_info" value="Y">Yes</label>`
....
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ojtm.inform_infoy").click(function(event) { 
        console.log("ojtm.inform_infoYY is clicked: ");
        //trying to do something                            
    });                     
});
</script>
```

I am trying to get its id using jquery to do something. But for some reason nothing is printing in console. How do I select that id inside label tag? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot is a [metacharacter](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in jquery, Escape it.

```
$("#ojtm\\.inform_infoy").click(function(event) {
```

And the best practice is to avoid using `.` in id/class attributes as it will cause problems like this. Additionally, you should prefer using `change` event over radio button instead of using `click` event.

Comment: Correct Answer. It solved my problem. I can accept the answer in 12 minutes. I dont know why I have that restriction.

Comment: @FarazDurrani That is not a restriction, That is the rule. And that rule says that `.` is a selector for classes. :)

Comment: lol no @Raja. I meant that why I have a 12 minute restriction to accept your answer I don't understand. lol I understand the jqeury rule :)

Comment: @FarazDurrani Oh, haha.. I misunderstood.